# Postgresql multicolumn index for BETWEEN and ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, nosql, b-tree

I have large table (100M records) with following structure.

```
  length   |          created_at
-----------+-------------------------------
 506225551 | 2018-12-29 02:08:34.116618
 133712971 | 2018-10-19 21:20:14.568936
 608443439 | 2018-12-14 03:22:55.141416
 927160571 | 2019-01-30 00:51:41.639126
 407033524 | 2018-11-16 21:26:41.523047
 506008096 | 2018-11-17 00:07:42.839919
 457719749 | 2018-11-12 02:32:53.116225
```

- `0 <  length < 1000000000`
- `'2017-01-01' < created_at < '2019-02-01'`
- data is evenly distributed for `length` and `created_at`.

I want to run queries like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE length BETWEEN 2000000 and 3000000 ORDER BY  created_at DESC
```

There are 100K results between 2000000 and 3000000, so I want to use index for selecting and for ordering.

I have tried these approaches

1. Simple BTREE index

```
create index on tbl(length);
```

This works well for short range for `length`, but I cannot use this index for ordering record.

2. Multicolumn BTREE index

```
 create index on tbl(length, created_at);
```

This index I can use only for queries like this

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE length = 2000000 ORDER BY  created_at DESC
```

3. GIST index with `btree_gist` extension. I expect, that this index should work.

```
create index on tbl using gist(length, created_at);
```

But it didn't. I cannot use this index even for simple query like this.

```
test=# explain analyze select * from gist_test where a = 345 order by c desc;

                                                                QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=25706.37..25730.36 rows=9597 width=12) (actual time=4.839..5.568 rows=10000 loops=1)
   Sort Key: c DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 853kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on gist_test  (cost=370.79..25071.60 rows=9597 width=12) (actual time=1.402..2.869 rows=10000 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (a = 345)
         Heap Blocks: exact=152
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gist_test_a_b_c_idx  (cost=0.00..368.39 rows=9597 width=0) (actual time=1.384..1.384 rows=10000 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (a = 345)
 Planning time: 0.119 ms
 Execution time: 6.271 ms
```

I can use this index only as simple BTREE on one column.

So, how can I solve this problem?

Maybe there is noSQL databases that can process queries of this kind?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to create index that will allow the query for any `length` range. If the possible ranges are limited (like up to 100) you can create partial indexes for each possible range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible (at least in vanilla postgresql, I do not know an extension that could help on that). The step of sorting records can be skipped only because indexes produce sorted records already.
However:

1. As mentioned in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html), only B-tree indexes can be used for sorting (which makes sense, it is implemented using a search tree).
2. Your `where` and your `order by` are incompatible for a B-tree index:

   - Because of having both clauses, you need to put 2 columns in the index `(A, B)`
   - Data in the index is sorted by `(A, B)`, therefore it is also sorted by `A` (which is why postgresql is able to index-scan the table fast when the `where` is on `A` only), but as a consequence, it is **not** sorted by `B` in the index (it is sorted by `B` only within each subset where `A` is constant, but not across the entire table).
   - As you probably already know, having an index on `B` only will be of little help because of the `where`.

The provided example #2 shows postgresql is well-optimized for the case you filter on a single value of `A`.

If it is unacceptable to sort on the 2 columns `(A, B)`, then I'm afraid you shouldn't expect more than this.